# How to change jquery animation value at window resize

Tags: jquery, animation, window-resize

I have a jquery animation according to the window width :

```
if(jQuery(window).width() >= 1100){     
    jQuery('#element1').mouseenter(function(){
        jQuery('#element2').animate({'top':'60px'},400);
    });
}
if(jQuery(window).width() < 1100){      
    jQuery('#element1').mouseenter(function(){
        jQuery('#element2').animate({'top':'120px'},400);
    });
}
```

When i resize the window screen, the animation does not follow it. I mean that when i open the browser screen at full size, for example 1400 px width, it works with the parameters as it should do but when i drag the screen to 800 px the animation makes the same animation (top 60px and not top 120px).

If i open the browser in 800px width, it gives the right animation (top 120px).

Is there a way to change the animation by browser screen drag that the visitor should not be obliged to refresh the page for the right animation ?

I do not know if i was enough clear, do not hesitate to ask me if not !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// wrap the code in a function to call it multiple times

function windowResize(){

//clear any old event bindings
jQuery('#element1').off("mouseenter");

if(jQuery(window).width() >= 1100){     
    jQuery('#element1').mouseenter(function(){
        jQuery('#element2').animate({'top':'60px'},400);
    });
   }

if(jQuery(window).width() < 1100){      
    jQuery('#element1').mouseenter(function(){
        jQuery('#element2').animate({'top':'120px'},400);
    });
   }    
}

// call it first time when page loads
windowResize(); 

// call it on window resize
$( window ).resize(windowResize);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! However, when i resize, the animation has an easeInBack (or something like it) effect now instead of a normal ease effect but it does not matter, it is quiet interesting like this... :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the problem you are having is because you are only querying the size of the window once, the code in this example shows the Jquery resize method being use to continuously update the window size therefore giving you the desired outcome.

```js
$("#reset").click(function() {
  $('#element2').animate({
    'top': '0px'
  }, 400);
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkSize();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  checkSize();
});

function checkSize() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 1100) {
    $('#element1').mouseenter(function() {
      $('#element2').animate({
        'top': '60px'
      }, 400)
    });
  }
  if ($(window).width() < 1100) {
    $('#element1').mouseenter(function() {
      $('#element2').animate({
        'top': '120px'
      }, 400);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
#element1,
#element2 {
  position: relative;
}
#element2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
            <![endif]-->

  <div id="element1">Move square</div>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  <div id="element2"></div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for you too ! I will check your solution as well, a bit later... thanks !